# Chinese Characters Are Misspelled in OI Operations

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, io

I try to write chinese character but take a wrong result

For Instance :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;

class x {

   public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {  
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = 
          new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("practice.csv"), true), "GBK");

        outputStreamWriter.write("常用场景"); 
        outputStreamWriter.write("Helo World!");
        outputStreamWriter.flush();
        outputStreamWriter.close(); 
    }
}
```

Response : ????¡±¡§??????Helo World!

I tried to change charset utf-8, utf-16 but it doesn't anything and lastly I tried to add BufferedWriter but unfortunately it doesn't anything again.

then I considered to change csv to txt, but again same result. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You're reading it wrong. Nothing wrong with the writing (except the flushing is unnecessary).

Comment: I removed the flush method but doesn't change anything, result is same again

Comment: I didn't say the flushing would affect it, just that it's unnecessary. But whatever you're using to read the file is not decoding things correctly, so that's your problem. Writing works fine, the part that gives you "Response: .." is wrong.

Comment: @Kayaman in fact, after this write process, I read the this csv file. When I added manuel chinese character to my csv file, It reads success. But write process is wrong. So It reads wrong from csv. What can I do for this situation. I have to use csv file for this process

Comment: @user16320675 I changed GBK to UTF-8, I took å¸¸ç”¨åœºæ™¯Helo World! by the way unfortunately I must use to GBK

Comment: You're only showing how you're writing the file, and there's nothing wrong with it. You need to show how you read it.

Comment: @Kayaman  I use this code pieces to the reading process.                        
                    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

            int b = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (b != -1) {
                b = inputStream.read(buffer);
                out.write(buffer, 0, b);
            }
            // .. Closing resources and catch block

Comment: @Kayaman I tried to UTF-8, GBK etc. for reading process but unfortunately it doesn't change anything

Comment: Verify the file with a byte viewer that the encoding is correct, then make sure you're sending the correct encoding to the client in headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it finally. Firstly very thanks for helping @Kayaman and @user16320675.

In fact, everything was correct. This problem's resource is csv files is opened by excel. When you want to open csv files directly in excel, it opens according to the encoding of the current computer language. We just have a option in Windows 10 EN(manually Data Import). I used the windows 10 EN and excel uses ANSI for windows 10 EN.

My Solution : I added to chinese language pack to my windows 10 computer and I changed the excel editing language (chinese for default) and everything worked.

Comment: Alternatively you could problaby saved your CSV in UTF-8 and written as first char, a BOM, `"\uFEFF"`.